# Excess models for VM

Tags: c#, wpf, oop, mvvm, solid-principles

Faced a problem when designing applications using WPF and the MVVM pattern.

A model is a single component (Suppose, Company).

```
class Company
{
    private string _Name;
    public ObservableCollection<Manager> Managers {get; set;}
    public ObservableCollection<Director> Directors {get; set;}
    public ObservableCollection<Tester> Testers {get; set;}
}
```

There is a VM and a View for this model. 
I will omit details like InotifyPropertyChanged, we will assume that they are implemented in the base ViewModel class, the Command and Mediator objects correspond to the implementation of classic patterns

```
class CompanyViewModel: ViewModel
{
   private Company _Company;

   public ICommand AddManagerCommand { get; }
   public ICommand AddTesterCommand { get; }
   public ICommand AddDirectorCommand { get; }

   public CompanyViewModel()
   {
      _Company = new Company();
      AddManagerCommand = new Command(OnAddManagerExecuted);
      AddTesterCommand = new Command(OnAddTesterExecuted);
      AddDirectorCommand = new Command(OnAddDirectorExecuted);

      Mediator.Register("GetManager", OnGetManager);
      ...
     ...

   }

    private void OnGetManager(object obj)
    {
        _Company.Managers.Add((Employee)obj);
    }
}
```

Inside this model, there are many objects that it includes. By analogy with the company, they can be represented as employees of the Manager, Director, Tester and they are all inherited from the Employee class.

```
class Employee
{
    public string Name {get; set;}
}
class Manager : Employee
{
    public string Age {get; set;}
    public string Sex {get; set;}
}
class Director : Employee
{
    public string Age {get; set;}
    public string Education {get; set;}
}
...
```

For editing each type of workers, its own presentation and its own VM are provided.

```
class ManagerViewModel : ViewModel
{
    public Command SaveCommand {get; private set;}

    public ManagerViewModel()
    {
        SaveCommand = new Command(OnSaveCommandExecuted)
    }

    private void OnSaveCommandExecuted(object window)
    {
        Mediator.NotifyColleggues("GetManager", new Manager())
    }
}
```

As a result, with this approach, I have a lot of VMs and views for each type of employee and for each of them my ObservableCollection in the Company model.
Thus, when adding a new type of employees, I have to inherit from Employee a new class, create a new VM, a new View, register a new message in Mediator to notify the VM Company about adding a new element to the ObservableCollection from the View of an new employee type and add a new Command to the VM Company to call the employee editing window. This architecture seems to me terribly rigid, and I would like to know what solution can help me increase the scalability of the system, perhaps some specific use of the Facade for models or Interfaces?

Comment: you don't necessarily need a VM for each person-type. how about making a generic VM that show's editable fields only if they exist for the given person type? (I'm learning MVVM myself, so I'm not 100% sure this will work, but maybe it helps to spark ideas)

Answer (score 0):

One trick that comes to my mind is to create one View+ViewModel - that helps you edit & save changes to a Dictionary. Next add methods to all your Models to help convert ToDictionary() and load FromDictionary().

That way to edit any Model, it will first be converted to a dictionary (Key being property Name and Value being the value to be edited). Then your View will help you edit the values (** tricky to do Datatype & business validations now **). Then on Save Command all you got to do is to update object back from Dictionary.

Obervation:
Model should not have ObservableCollection.

Comment: I'm not sure that this is exactly the solution I need, but I think about using DataTemplate.
And where should I take out the ObservableCollection?

Comment: DataTemplate is coupled to the Data bound to the control/view. So that means for every Model you have now/in future you will have to add new Data Template for it. In short all you are saving on is creating new UserControl (xaml file). ObservableCollections are used for Binding and should be in VM (preferably). So your Company model (in ex above) should have List<> or IList<> of Managers. While in the VM you can have ObservableCollection<Company> if there many of it.